# Pushdown Automata in Haskell using the List Monad

Tags: haskell, monads, pushdown-automaton

I'm trying to implement Pushdown Automata (as described in Sipser's Introduction to the Theory of Computation) in Haskell. I have a working definition:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe(fromMaybe)

-- A Pushdown Automaton with states of type q,
-- inputs of type s, and a stack of type g
data PDA q s g = P { state :: [q]
                   , start :: q
                   , delta :: [Rule q s g]
                   -- the transition function is list of relations
                   , final :: [q]  -- list of accept states
                   }

-- rules are mappings from a (state, Maybe input, Maybe stack) to
-- a list of (state, Maybe stack)
-- Nothing represents the empty element ε
type Rule q s g = ((q, Maybe s, Maybe g), [(q, Maybe g)])

push :: Maybe a -> [a] -> [a]
push (Just x) xs = x:xs
push Nothing  xs = xs

-- returns the popped element and the stack without that element
pop :: [a] -> (Maybe a, [a])
pop (x:xs) = (Just x, xs)
pop [] = (Nothing, [])

lookup' :: Eq a => a -> [(a, [b])] -> [b]
lookup' a xs = fromMaybe [] (lookup a xs)

-- calls deltaStar with the start state and an empty stack,
-- and checks if any of the resulting states are accept states
accepts :: (Eq q, Eq s, Eq g) => PDA g s q -> [s] -> Bool
accepts p xs = any ((`elem` final p). fst) $ deltaStar (start p) (delta p) xs []

deltaStar :: (Eq q, Eq s, Eq g)
          => q  -- the current state
          -> [Rule q s g] -- delta
          -> [s] -- inputs
          -> [g] -- the stack
          -> [(q, Maybe g)]
deltaStar q rs (x:xs) st = nub . concat $
  map (\(a, b) -> deltaStar a rs xs $ push b stack)
    (lookup' (q, Just x, fst $ pop st) rs) ++
  map (\(a, b) -> deltaStar a rs (x:xs) $ push b stack)
    (lookup' (q, Nothing, fst $ pop st) rs) ++
  map (\(a, b) -> deltaStar a rs xs $ push b st)
    (lookup' (q, Just x, Nothing) rs) ++
  map (\(a, b) -> deltaStar a rs (x:xs) $ push b st)
    (lookup' (q, Nothing, Nothing) rs)
  where stack = snd $ pop st
deltaStar q rs [] st = nub $ (q, Nothing)
                           : lookup' (q, Nothing, fst $ pop st) rs
                           ++ lookup' (q, Nothing, Nothing) rs
```

Which gives me the expected results. However, looking at my `deltaStar` function, I can't help but feel there must be a more elegant way to write it. I manually check for Transitions that have ε in the input or stack, which I don't think I can get around, but this kind of Non-Determinism using concat and map looks like the `List` Monad to me. I would love to be able to write something like

```
deltaStar q rs (x:xs) st = do
(a, b) <- lookup' (q, Just x, fst $ pop st) rs
(c, d) <- lookup' (q, Nothing, fst $ pop st) rs
(e, f) <- lookup' (q, Just x, Nothing) rs
(g, h) <- lookup' (q, Nothing, Nothing) rs
concat [ deltaStar a rs xs $ push b stack
      , deltaStar c rs (x:xs) $ push d stack
      , deltaStar e rs xs $ push f st
      , deltaStar g rs (x:xs) $ push h st]
where stack = snd $ pop st
deltaStar q rs [] st = nub $ (q, Nothing)
                           : lookup' (q, Nothing, fst $ pop st) rs
                           ++ lookup' (q, Nothing, Nothing) rs
```

But that `deltaStar` will almost always return `[]`, as when any of the pattern binds fail, the whole computation will return `[]`. Is there a solution to this or should I stick to my definition?

I tested my original function with the language `True^n False^n`, defined as such:

```
langA :: PDA Int Bool Char
langA = P [1,2,3,4]
          1
          delta
          [1,4]
  where delta = [ ((1, Nothing, Nothing), [(2, Just '$')])
                , ((2, Just False, Nothing),[(2, Just '0')])
                , ((2, Just True, Just '0'), [(3, Nothing)])
                , ((3, Just True, Just '0'), [(3, Nothing)])
                , ((3, Nothing, Just '$'), [(4, Nothing)])]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Li-yao Xia's answer shows how to use more typeclass-polymorphic operations, but doesn't address the code duplication. In this answer I show how to address that. The main idea is this: there are just two things that vary, and they vary independently, namely whether we consume a letter and whether we consume from the stack. So let's nondeterministically choose for each!

(Warning: untested code follows.)

```
deltaStar q rs (x:xs) st = do
    (stackSymbol, st') <- [pop st, (Nothing, st)]
    (stringSymbol, xs') <- [(Just x, xs), (Nothing, x:xs)]
    (a, b) <- lookup' (q, stringSymbol, stackSymbol) rs
    deltaStar a rs xs' (push b st')
```

Comment: This works perfectly and is exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In the original definition, `(++)` separates the lookups, which corresponds to choice `(<|>)` in the nondeterministic interpretation of `[]`.

```
deltaStar q rs (x:xs) st = nub . asum $
  [ do (a, b) <- lookup' (q, Just x, fst $ pop st) rs
       deltaStar a rs xs $ push b stack
  , do (a, b) <- lookup' (q, Nothing, fst $ pop st) rs
       deltaStar a rs (x:xs) $ push b stack
  , do (a, b) <- lookup' (q, Just x, Nothing) rs
       deltaStar a rs xs $ push b st
  , do (a, b) <- lookup' (q, Nothing, Nothing) rs
       deltaStar a rs (x:xs) $ push b st
  ] where stack = snd $ pop st
-- asum [a, b, c d] = a <|> b <|> c <|> d = a ++ b ++ c ++ d
--                  = concat [a, b, c, d]
```

Comment: I haven't used the `Alternative` typeclass yet, could you explain why it's a better fit than simply using `concat` here?

Comment: It's not really a better fit, it's mostly personal preference. But the point of mentioning it is that with the abstract view of `[]` as a nondeterminism monad, you need more operations than just `(>>=)` and `return` to write this program, and `Alternative` provides the operations you need here.